# Why can't I make the mountains in the background move in a parallax fashion?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, game-engine, physics, game-physics

So, I want to make the backgrounds move in relation to the player, Trump. How do I do this?

```
var trump : Rigidbody2D;
var mountain = GetComponent(Rigidbody2D);

function fixedUpdate() {
    mountain.position.x = trump.position.x * 2;
    mountain.position.y = trump.position.y * 2;
    if (mountain.position.y <= 0) {
        mountain.velocity.y = 0;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: i really suggest you just get a parallax pack from the asset store, or a free one from a wiki.  SO is really not suitable for extremely general technique questions.  What about gamedev.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your mountains need RigidBody components - these are intended for objects that perform collisions and relate to physics properties in game.

The normal procedure for moving a gameobject around a scene is the Gameobject's Transform component, which has a Position property you can modify.

*Excuse the C#.*

```
[SerializeField] private Transform _mountainRoot;
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D _trumpBody;

[SerializeField, Range(0f, 1f)] private float _parallaxFactor = 0.75f;

private Vector2 _lastTrumpPos;

private void Update()
{
    // get the amount Trump moved since last update
    float deltaTrumpPosX = _trumpBody.position.x - _lastTrumpPos.x;

    // move the mountains by a factor of this movement 
    _mountainRoot.transform.Translate(deltaTrumpPosX * _parallaxFactor, 0f, 0f);

    // cache position value to use on next update cycle
    _lastTrumpPos = _trumpBody.position;
}
```

Here you take the Transform of the mountains as what you intend to manipulate the position of, and the Rigidbody2D from your character. Additionally you take a normal value (0 to 1, think of it as a percentage between 0 and 100) to scale the parallax effect by.

In this Update() loop we **first find out how much the character has moved since last update**. We compare it's current position to the position we recorded it in, during last update, and subtract, leaving the difference/delta.

Then we **apply this delta value with our scaling factor** to the mountains. Transform.Translate() is a function that modifies the position, in this case we just want the X/horizontal value to be modified.

Finally, we **record the character's position** in the world overwriting the previous value - so we can use it to calculate the delta next update.

Comment: note too that in reality, you often just do this by offsetting the texture. (it makes it easier to wrap, apart from anything else!)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to translate it to javascript, and it worked well! Plus. i had fixedUpdate() instead of FixedUpdate()